# Field depandancy module can not work for textfield in field collection

Tags: 7, entities

I am using field dependency module for use only 1 field

I have 2 fields text and image user can use only 1 field text or image if user can select text field other will be hidden or invisible
same case with image to text field

here is conditions:

case 1:

```
Dependent:Image (field_image)
Dependees:Text (field_text)
Description:Image is invisible when Text is filled.
```

case 2:

```
Dependent:Text (field_text)
Dependees:Image (field_image)
Description:Text is invisible when Image is filled.
```

case 1 is working perfectly but case 2 is not working.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which define dependencies between fields based on their states and values. Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields.

Thank you.